# Angular routing with params, redirect route with params separately from one without params

Tags: angular, angular-router

In an Angular (v7) application, I have routing setup like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: Main
    },
    {
      path: 'main',
      component: Main
    },
     {
      path: 'search/:imageid',
      component: Image
    }, 
    {
      path: 'search',
      component: Search
    }]
}]
```

What I'm expecting to happen, is for a URL like this:

```
domain.com/#/search;imageid=512
```

The router will redirect to the Image component, and for a URL like this:

```
domain.com/#/search
```

The router will redirect to the Search component, but Search is getting both, and the route to Image is being bypassed.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the name of your path variable.

The path you should use is `domain.com/#/search/512` and the router will handle the variable as expected.

(make sure you correctly defined your `HashLocationStrategy`).

Also, it can be useful to know the existence of the `pathMatch: 'full'` property on routes, that allows to match the whole path and not just the prefix. It could be the issue here, but it is not because of the order in which you put the children routes. Have a look at [this place in the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects) for a more precise development.